# c# Exception handling in 3 tier win forms app

Tags: c#, exception, n-tier-architecture

I have a 3 tier win forms app, it has a UI, BLL and DAL. I'm looking to add an exception handler that throws exceptions from the DAL all the way up to the UI so the user knows what the error is. I have tried using try{} catch{} and throwing it from the DAL, but this only throws it up to the BLL and stops there. is there any way to throw it right back to the UI?

Thanks

EDIT:

CODE:

http://pastebin.com/V75MDWdm

Comment: can you show us your catch code in the BLL?

Comment: @stecya: do you have anything to demonstrate this?

Comment: or, just don't use catch in the BLL...

Comment: In your code the BLL rethrows the exception, what catches it?

Comment: @Funky, FYI: When you want to "re-throw" an exception simply use throw; and not throw ex as you are doing. I don't really understand your problem but I thought I'd mention this after seeing your code.

Comment: @Funky - Another point. When you say "Tier" it implies physical boundaries, that is your application is distributed across 3 physical tiers (3 different machines or 3 different applications on  one or more machines). Just so we're all on the same page. Is your application a 3 layered app or a 3 tiered app? If it's a 3 tiered application what are you using to communicate between the tiers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each layer should wrap the exception in a slightly more abstract exception.

For example, take a simple customer logon operation:

- DAL throws a "RecordNotFound" exception when trying to load a "customer" record.
- BLL catches it, and wraps it in a "InvalidLogonRequest" exception, saying the customer record was not found.
- GUI catches that, and displays an error message to the user saying the "customer" does not exist.

Each layer below the UI does not necessarily know the wider context of the operation which is in progress, so it's up to the layer above to provide more contextual information about what went wrong...

Maybe a better example would be a cusomer registration operation:

- DAL throws a  sql "UniqueConstraintException" on the email address column.

  - The DAL perhaps doesn't know that this is a registration process, it only knows it's doing an INSERT into the customer table...
- BLL catches that, and throws a "EmailAlreadyExists" exception.
- GUI catches that, and displays an message to the user "the email address is already taken"

Comment: Hold on, he said his exception "stopped" in the BLL. How does he then catch it in the GUI?

Comment: Exceptions from the data access layer should not bubble up to the presentation layer. The data exception does indeed "stop" in the BLL. But the BLL should throw a more contextual exception itself, which the GUI should catch.

Comment: Excellent, and use InnerException to store the 'UniqueConstraintException' in the BLL. Good for debugging / error reporting

Answer (score 2):

The Code provided seems to use a generic Exception to relate the error. this is probably a bad idea, as if you catch any Exceptions anywhere else, that code could easily be consuming this Exception as well when you dont expect it to.

I would specify some custom exceptions for this specific error, and specifically catch/rethrow those Exceptions. using base class Exception will just lead to confusion between different catches in different places.